# django serve video as blob

Tags: django, google-chrome, video, safari, webkit

> django 3.2.8; safari Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.7)

> for `mp4` and `mov`, safari does not work, chrome and opera does.

##### relative useful posts

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913160/11645617
- https://wpmudev.com/forums/topic/mp4-videos-not-loading-on-safari/
- [Failed to Load Resource, Plugin Handled Load on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103103/failed-to-load-resource-plugin-handled-load-on-ios)

Hi there, I am trying to build a simple video app with django on my local machine.

```py
class Video(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnail', blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='video', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mov', 'MOV','avi','mp4', 'MP4','webm','mkv'])])
```

> list view

```html
{% for video in page_obj.object_list %}
    <video width="400" 
    height="350" 
    controls 
    {% if video.thumbnail %}
    poster="{{ video.thumbnail.url }}"
    {% endif %}
    >
    <source src=
    "{{ video.file.url }}"
        type="video/mov">
    </video>
{% endfor %}
```

Video is not playing on Safari.

```
Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load
```

in terminal

```
[20/Dec/2021 03:14:16,147] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 50812)
```

I wonder why this happens, will be grateful for your help.

---

#### what I have tried

> add `raw="true"` to video tag

```
did not work, still the same result
```

> transcoding video to web optimised by handbrake

```
some videos that did not work on Chrome and Opera started to work 
But, not for Safari
```

> tries to embed an YouTube iframe

```
always works on safari
```

---

I suspect the issue is on `file server`, which I served the video as a file. Safari and chrome requires the video to be served as `blob`, I wonder if there is a way to do it, appreciate for your help.

Comment: Your main goal is to make video player working on local machine or prepare it for production?

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak sorry a bit confusion here, isn't making the player working on my local machine the first step to prepare it for production? I cannot get it working on my machine now, in safari and chrome.

Comment: @Weilory Can you replace `{{ video.file.url }}` with some `https://` video URL and test if it's problem with your local videofile?